# Creating a Gazebo World using a Ground Truth Model

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I am just starting off with Gazebo to perform some multirobot simulations. In order to keep our project relevant to the topic, I wanted to perform these simulations in a visually relevant environment rather than a box world with obstacles. We have some ground truth models created using Faro Scans of the test site. I wanted to use these models as my Gazebo world and perform the simulations in there. Does anyone know if it is possible ?
Thanks
Ammar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47343/creating-a-gazebo-world-using-a-ground-truth-model/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume the Faro scans are point cloud data. You would have to create a polygon representation out of that (for example using Meshlab) and save that as a .dae or .stl file. You can then use that inside a gazebo model and load it.

I did the same with a landscape modeled in Blender (COLLADA named "120m_landscape_smooth_tri.dae").

Here's the world file for electric's gazebo:
http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/electric/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_worlds/worlds/rolling_landscape_120m.world

and here for fuerte:
http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/fuerte/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_worlds/worlds/rolling_landscape_120m.world

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on 2012-11-02**:
Great! That makes sense. Thank you!